# typescript semantic difference between generic class methods and generic classes

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm a bit puzzled as to why the example code below works when I use class generics, but not when I use method generics.

To start off I have simple `Request` and `Response` classes:

```
abstract class BaseRequest {
  baseProperty: string;
}

class ChildRequest extends BaseRequest {
  childProperty: string;
}

abstract class BaseResponse<R extends BaseRequest> {
  data: any;
  request: R;
}

class ChildResponse extends BaseResponse<ChildRequest> {
}
```

To keep my inheritance simple I **want** to use the generic method code below (note the class is not generic, only the method and extending the base class requires no generics):

```
abstract class RequestClient {
  abstract request<RQ extends BaseRequest, RP extends BaseResponse<RQ>>(request: RQ): RP;
}


class ChildClient extends RequestClient {
  request(request: ChildRequest): ChildResponse {
    return undefined;   // just testing the code structure right now
  }
}
```

But the compiler compains on `ChildClient.request`:

```
TS2416: Property 'request' in type 'ChildClient' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'RequestClient'.
  Type '(request: ChildRequest) => ChildResponse' is not assignable to type '<RQ extends BaseRequest, RP extends BaseResponse<RQ>>(request: RQ) => RP'.
    Types of parameters 'request' and 'request' are incompatible.
      Type 'RQ' is not assignable to type 'ChildRequest'.
        Type 'BaseRequest' is not assignable to type 'ChildRequest'.
          Property 'childProperty' is missing in type 'BaseRequest'.
```

However, using class generics works fine:

```
abstract class RequestClient<RQ extends BaseRequest, RP extends BaseResponse<RQ>> {
  abstract request(request: RQ): RP;
}

class ChildClient extends RequestClient<ChildRequest, ChildResponse> {
  request(request: ChildRequest): ChildResponse {
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

I want to avoid class generics because it starts creating a class inheritance trickle down explosion where I end up having tons of useless child classes just to get the generic method to compile correctly.

Why does class generics work, but not method generics? What is the semantic difference here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in the generic-method example, your child class violates the contract defined by the base class.

The base class promises that an instance of that class allows the caller to choose any type of request and response, but the child class overrides the request method and restricts the contract: nope, I can only send a ChildRequest, and you will only get back a ChildResponse.

Think about the following situation:

```
const client: RequestClient = new ChildClient();
```

This is valid, since ChildClient extends RequestClient. So, since the client is  RequestClient, you can do

```
const response: MyResponse = client.request<MyRequest, MyResponse>(new MyRequest());
```

Which method would be called if what you want was accepted by the compiler? What would happen?

Comment: Ah yeah. Got lost in the weeds there. Thanks for the example situation. That really made it clear why the compiler was barking at me.